# Python: PyGame drawing RECTANGLE help(BEGINNER)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am just learning how to use *Pygame* but when I run the program the Pygame window is just black and there is no **rectangle**? Can anyone help?

```
         import pygame, sys
         from pygame.locals import *

         pygame.init()
         screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)



         while True:
             for event in pygame.event.get():
                 if event.type==QUIT:
                     pygame.quit()
                     sys.exit()

         screen.lock()
         pygame.draw.rect (screen, (140,240,130), Rect((100,100), (130,170)))
         screen.unlock()   




         pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to lock the screen.

The problem is you're not drawing in your loop.

```
     import pygame, sys
     from pygame.locals import *

     pygame.init()
     screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)



     while True:
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type==QUIT:
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()


         screen.fill((255,255,255))        
         pygame.draw.rect (screen, (140,240,130), Rect((100,100), (130,170)))
         pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated. All you need to do is:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 320))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (140,240,130), (100, 100, 130, 170), 0)
pygame.display.flip()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
pygame.quit()
```

The `pygame.display.flip()` part is the same thing as `pygame.display.update()`